# MySQL denied my access from a Java program but not from command line

Tags: java, mysql, access-denied

I installed MySQL on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I could login with root from the command line. But when I run the following java program, I received an access denied exception. What was wrong?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Conn {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"
            + "localhost" + "/xi_tong?characterEncoding=utf8", "root",
            "****");
    }
}
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at Conn.main(Conn.java:7)
```

I could login from the command line:

```
zirui@52:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 104
Server version: 5.5.55-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input 
statement.

mysql>
```

On another machine:

```
zirui@45:~/Server/src$ java -cp .:mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar Conn
zirui@45:~/Server/src$
```

Comment: replace **"****"** with the password

Comment: @Ali: I substituted the real password by **** for security reasons. The password was not a problem as I could login from shell.

Comment: i think you are misplacing something please check your code or rebuild your project and run

Comment: I tried this program on another machine and changed "localhost" to this machine's IP. The program passed! I suspect that the problem is with MySQL configurations.

Comment: `localhost:3306` the port not specified

Comment: which version of mysql you are using

Comment: @Ali: No, still access denied.

Comment: @jishnuradhakrishnan: Server version: 5.5.55-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu).

Comment: do you add the database to `root`

Comment: are you able to access the database using username:root , in your mysql from console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with privileges!
[image: The problem is with privileges!]

Answer (score 1):

Ensure db exists.

```
USE yourdb;
```

I recently had a problem like this where the dbname was wrong typed.

Comment: I purposely changed the DB name to a wrong one and still got this error. The database didn't proceed to the database selection step. It was an "access denied" error. My original DB name was correct. "Use xi_tong" returned no error.